# Date a GNU/Linux or Unix program was first released

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, gnu, unix-utils

When I uncover a new command, most recently `column`,  I am curious as to how long this command has existed -- in appreciation of the longevity of Unix, its dedicated developers, and my own ignorance!  Is there a machine local or online resource that provides the date a command was first released? I assume this may be OS/distro specific, but any pointers as to where I can delve into the history of these command would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to post this question in [Retro Computing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/ shows each Ubuntu distro and by stepping back in time, you can see when a package appears. FreeBSD has https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=column&stype=name&sektion=all and other distros probably have a similar web page, probably found with a search term of DISTRONAME PACKAGE - and since this is a question of fact and not likely to either outdate quickly or attract opnion-based answers, I am perplexed by the downcheck.

Comment: @Mihail has the correct answer, and was released in 1986. I also found this out a different way by visiting the source code on github: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/text-utils/column.c. So, answer is, read the man page (more carefully on my part!), or search the internet for the source code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The column command appeared in BSD 4.3 Reno .

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/column.htm